# How to merge red channel with gray scale image with opencv python?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have two microscope images. One in gray scale, one in red. I can merge these in photoshop, imagej, etc. I want to merge these two in opencv so I can perform this operation on many samples.

So far I've done the following (where dia=grayscale and epi=red).

```
# Load images
img_dia = cv2.imread(input_dia)
img_epi = cv2.imread(input_epi)

# Slice red channel from fluorescence image
b_epi, g_epi, r_epi = cv2.split(img_epi)

# Now I want to merge the grey scale and red image
```

No error messages. I could not find any documentation or other stack exchange pages to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Merge" how exactly? Could you show an example of the input images, and what the result should look like?

Comment: An example of what you want to do would help. You do not have enough privileges to add images directly, yet, but I believe that you can post images to some free hosting service and put the URLs here.

Comment: Hello, sorry for not providing an example. This is one of my first posts.

Here is a public google doc to show how I generated the image in imageJ (fiji), the input images and the output. I appreciate the help!

https://docs.google.com/document/d/13dEWfwHl6wZFkNAh6EJmZLSz5xTFLzxJprXIG_1U3v0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Cool. Please provide the 2 input images and the expected result - I think I have a good solution for you.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, were you able to open the public google doc in my comment just above yours? It has the 2 inputs and expected result you mentioned.

Thanks!

Comment: I was hoping to get the separate individual images, rather than a document containing pictures of the images. I'm also currently away from any computers so I'll have a look again when I return home at the weekend.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell , It doesn't look like I can upload the images because they are larger than 2mb. They are 3mb each. Do you have a suggestion of how to upload?

Comment: You can share a Dropbox link or a Google Drive link...

Comment: Grey: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FHPUBFmoe3juf4Pbfwh4pBui0U2yIBe5/view?usp=sharing -- Red: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qMYfTw7Yo744AIz3ZBWWG-bmEF2KNQ4q/view?usp=sharing -- Merge: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10FIkw21XjFrORGdPcHMXhznjJjjfgbhc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of overlaying and blending images, but I think the nearest result to yours is probably **screen**-mode blending.

You can get what you want quite simply with **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. So, just in Terminal (or Command Prompt on Windows), you can run the following without needing to write any code:

```
magick grey.tif red.tif -compose screen -composite  result.png
```

[image]

If that is not the exact blend-mode you want, there 69 modes available in **ImageMagick** and you can see them all listed if you run:

```
magick -list compose
```

So, if you want **Hard Light** blending, use:

```
magick grey.tif red.tif -compose HardLight -composite  result.png
```

You alluded to having lots of images to do, if so, you can get thousands done in parallel just by using **GNU Parallel**. You can search for answers on Stack Overflow that use ImageMagick and GNU Parallel by putting the following in the Stack Overflow **Search** box, including the square brackets:

```
[imagemagick] [gnu-parallel]
```

Or, provide some more detail on how your files are named and stored and I can help you further.

Comment: This is amazing!! Thank you so much

Comment: Cool - I'm glad it works for you! Feel free to accept it as the answer by clicking on the holllow tick ✅ beside the vote count.

Answer (score 0):

considering `input_epi` is an RGB image(3 channels)

when you load an image into opencv it is loaded as BGR by default

```
# colour image
img_epi = cv2.imread('input_epi.jpg')

# red channel
red_epi = img_epi[:,:,2]

# gray image
img_dia = cv2.imread('input_dia',0)

# creating a resultant image for combining only two channels
resultant_image = np.ones((img_dia.shape[0],img_dia.shape[1],2),np.uint8)

# merge two channels into a single two channel array
# first channel red
resultant_image[:,:,0] = red_epi
# second channel gray
resultant_image[:,:,1] = img_dia
```

[Splitting and Merging Image Channels](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html?#splitting-and-merging-image-channels)

In OpenCV Documentation

**Warning cv2.split() is a costly operation (in terms of time). So do it only if you need it. Otherwise go for Numpy indexing.**

Actual red colour is tricky to pin point from a `RGB` image better to use `HSV` to extract particular range of colour from an image

Comment: Thanks! 

Does using 'np.uint8' convert the image to 8bit? One thing to note is that in imagej, I have to convert both grey and red to image type '8 bit', then merge channels, then merge back from '8 bit' to 'RGB Color'

Comment: check the [Data Types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html?#array-types-and-conversions-between-types) explanation, images are stored in unsigned int 8 bit `uint8`. Load an image and check for yourself `print(img.dtype)`